# Yocto doesn't copy libphp7.so to rootfs

Tags: php, apache2, yocto

To add the php apache2 module in Yocto I created a file `recipes-devtools/php/php_%.bbappend` with the following content:

```
PACKAGECONFIG = " mysql sqlite3 imap opcache openssl ${@bb.utils.filter('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'ipv6 pam', d)} apache2"

LIBS_pn-php =" -lpthread "
export LIBS
THREADS_pn-php = "pthread"
export THREADS
```

The module is built, but the file `tmp-glibc/sysroots-components/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4/php/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.so` is not copied to the rootfs (`/usr/lib/apache2/modules/`).

1. Why it does not deploy the file?
2. As temporary workaround (and to learn how to handle Yocto's path) I'm trying to manually deploy it with a `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND`. To avoid absolute paths, what variable should I use to find out the file above under the `tmp-glibc` output dir? Something like:

   `${TMPDIR}/sysroots-components/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4/php/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.so`

or there's something better?

Comment: Have you checked that the file gets both deployed through the `do_install` command as well as packaged through `FILES_`?

Comment: Maybe add in `php_%.bbappend` something like `FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/apache2"` ? Try `oe-pkgdata-util list-pkg-files -p php` to see where files are packaged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Yocto, **files** (which are installed in `${D}` either manually in `do_install` or by the make, cmake, autotools, etc... in e.g. `do_compile`) **are put in a package when they match one of the regular expression** (or glob, not entirely sure about that) **contained in `FILES_foo`.**

**One recipe can (and usually does) provide multiple packages.** So you'd have multiple `FILES_foo1` with their own paths to match.

In Yocto, the file is put in the first package where one of the paths in its `FILE_foo` matches the file. **Even if the file matches the paths of other packages, it'll ever be in only one package, the first one.**

FWIW, **packages are created from leftmost to rightmost in `PACKAGES`** variable in the recipe. By default, the PACKAGES variable is `${PN}-src ${PN}-dbg ${PN}-staticdev ${PN}-dev ${PN}-doc ${PN}-locale ${PACKAGE_BEFORE_PN} ${PN}` (c.f. http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n292).

The default `FILES_*` variables are defined in bitbake.conf as well, c.f. http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf. Look for everything starting with `FILES_`.

In there, you can see that by default, `FILES_${PN}` has `${libdir}/lib*${SOLIBS}` (c.f. http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n296) packaged. `SOLIBS` is, by default, `.so.*` (c.f. http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n280), **which means only dot versions of libraries are packaged in the `${PN}` package** (if they are not matched by another package before).
`FILES_${PN}-dev` on the other hand packages `${FILES_SOLIBSDEV}` which defaults to `${base_libdir}/lib*${SOLIBSDEV} ${libdir}/lib*${SOLIBSDEV}`, with `SOLIBSDEV` in turns defaults to `.so` (c.f. http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n313, http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n314 and http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n283).
Please note that library filenames should all start with `lib` to be able to be matched by the default `FILES_*`.

**TL;DR: By default, `lib*.so.*` in `FILES_${PN}` and `lib*.so` in `FILES_${PN}-dev`.**

For your specific issue, you can see that `${libdir}/apache2` directory is packaged in `php-modphp` thanks to `FILES_${PN}-modphp` (c.f. http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/php/php.inc#n243).

**So you need to add php-modphp (assuming `${PN}` resolves to php) to your image to be able for the lib to be installed in your rootfs.**